# Grant and Revoke on a table in Informix

Tags: informix, sql-grant, dml

If I try to execute

```
      create table TEST(testColumn VARCHAR(255));
      grant insert on TEST to test_user;
      revoke insert on TEST from test_user;
```

I get the following error message (translated from German by myself):

```
1) [REVOKE - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs] [Error Code: -580, SQL State: IX000]
   Could not detract access rights.
2) [Error Code: -111, SQL State: IX000]  ISAM-Error: No data record was found.
```

(English version of error -580: *Cannot revoke permission.*)

Do you have any idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the statements are issued with the same user?

Usually this happens when trying to revoke a table-level privilege that your account name did not grant.

To find the correct grantee use:

```
    SELECT  a.grantee,  a.grantor
    FROM    systabauth a, systables t
    WHERE   a.tabid = t.tabid
            AND UPPER(t.tabname) =  'TEST';
```

Then it's possible to issue:

```
REVOKE INSERT ON TEST FROM 'test_user' AS '<GRANTEE>';
```

The other possibility that I didn’t mention, but @chris311 figure it out, is that [you cannot revoke privileges from yourself](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0945.htm?lang=en).

What is happening “behind it”, take the next example, a database named **chris311**, owned by **chris**, bear in mind that I'm using the **informix** user:

```
[infx1210@tardis ~]$ id
uid=501(informix) gid=501(informix) groups=501(informix)
[infx1210@tardis ~]$ dbaccess chris311 -

Database selected.

> SELECT    name, owner
> FROM      sysmaster:sysdatabases
> WHERE     name = DBINFO('dbname') ;

name   chris311
owner  chris

1 row(s) retrieved.

>
```

Both **chris** and **informix** have the **DBA** database-level privilege, and **ricardo** was granted the **CONNECT** privilege:

```
> SELECT username, usertype
> FROM   sysusers;


username                        usertype

chris                           D
informix                        D
ricardo                         C

3 row(s) retrieved.

>
```

There is a table, **tab1**, owned by **chris** that **ricardo** was granted, by **chris**, the **ALL** table-level privilege:

```
> SELECT    t.tabname, t.owner, a.grantee,  a.tabauth, a.grantor
> FROM      systabauth a, systables t
> WHERE     a.tabid = t.tabid
>           AND t.tabname=  'tab1';

tabname     tab1
owner       chris
grantee     ricardo
tabauth     su-idxar-
grantor     chris

1 row(s) retrieved.

>
```

Then if **informix** whant's to revoke the **INSERT** privilege it must use the **AS** clause to specify **chris** as the revoker:

```
> REVOKE INSERT ON tab1 FROM ricardo;

  580: Cannot revoke permission.

  111: ISAM error:  no record found.
Error in line 1
Near character position 33
> REVOKE INSERT ON tab1 FROM ricardo AS chris;

Permission revoked.

> SELECT    t.tabname, t.owner, a.grantee,  a.tabauth, a.grantor
> FROM      systabauth a, systables t
> WHERE     a.tabid = t.tabid
>           AND t.tabname = 'tab1';


tabname  tab1
owner    chris
grantee  ricardo
tabauth  su--dxar-
grantor  chris

1 row(s) retrieved.

>
```

If he tries to revoke  the **INSERT** privilege  from himself an error will return also:

```
> REVOKE INSERT ON tab1 FROM informix;

  580: Cannot revoke permission.

  111: ISAM error:  no record found.
Error in line 1
Near character position 34
>
```

Now if we see the meaning of the 580 error we get:

```
[infx1210@tardis ~]$ finderr 580
-580    Cannot revoke permission.

This REVOKE statement cannot be carried out. Either it revokes a
database-level privilege, but you are not a Database Administrator in
this database, or it revokes a table-level privilege that your account
name did not grant. Review the privilege and the user names in the
statement to ensure that they are correct. To summarize the table-level
privileges you have granted, query systabauth as follows:

SELECT A.grantee, T.tabname FROM systabauth A, systables T
        WHERE A.grantor = USER AND A.tabid = T.tabid


[infx1210@tardis ~]$
```

It doesn't says anything about revoking privileges from himself, but the documentations mentions it. Also, if we think about the `111: ISAM error:  no record found.` and associate it to the fact that the **DBA** doesn´t appear on the `systabauth` it makes sence, kind of.

The grants doesn´t return an error/warning because the **DBA** already have the privileges, the revoke returns it because the action didn't take effect.

Now let's take the **DBA** role from **chris**, let's do it twice:

```
> REVOKE DBA FROM chris;

Permission revoked.

> REVOKE DBA FROM chris;

Permission revoked.

> SELECT username, usertype
> FROM   sysusers;

username                        usertype

chris                           C
informix                        D
ricardo                         C

3 row(s) retrieved.

> SELECT    t.tabname, t.owner, a.grantee,  a.tabauth, a.grantor
> FROM      systabauth a, systables t
> WHERE     a.tabid = t.tabid
>           AND t.tabname=  'tab1';



tabname  tab1
owner    chris
grantee  ricardo
tabauth  su--dxar-
grantor  chris

1 row(s) retrieved.

>
```

Again, the second **REVOKE** didn't return an error/warning because it was in effect. The user still doesn´t appear on the `systabauth` table.

But what table-level privileges it has?

```
[infx1210@tardis ~]$ dbaccess chris311 -

Database selected.

> INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES(1);

1 row(s) inserted.

> SELECT * FROM tab1;


       col1

          1

1 row(s) retrieved.

> DROP TABLE tab1;

Table dropped.

>
```

He isn't a **DBA** but he is the owner.

Comment: Yes, every statement is executed by the same user.

Comment: The problem was, that test_user was the same user as the grantor. If I use a different user, it works.

Comment: Yes, you cannot revoke privileges from yourself. [doc](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0945.htm?lang=en)